Error function to conditionally count observations by group
I am working with the following example survey data:
df <- data.frame(county=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                          "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
                 response=c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), 
                 value=sample(20:100, 15, replace=TRUE))

If sum(df$response[df$county == K]) < 3  for K set to any of the characters in $county  the data cannot be shared for confidentiality reasons. I am trying to write a "simple" function that will create an error or warning indicating that a county has less than three observations. Ideally, the function would indicate the problem county from the warning/error message. County B above is an example of a county that does not meet the minimum confidentiality threshold.
I have tried iterations of functions like this that are obviously wrong.
my_funct <- function(x) {
  if (any(x > 3)) stop("Error")
}

Any suggestions or direction would be greatly appreciated.

A base R approach using warning within aggregate
aggregate(response ~ county, df, \(x) 
  ifelse(sum(x) < 3, warning("Not OK", immediate.=T), "OK"))

output
Warning in ifelse(sum(x) < 3, warning("Not OK", immediate. = T), "OK") :
  Not OK
  county response
1      A       OK
2      B   Not OK
3      C       OK


If you also want the normal output with the warning try
aggregate(response ~ county, df, \(x) 
  c(out = sum(x), 
    warning = ifelse(sum(x) < 3, warning("Not OK", immediate.=T), "OK")))

output
Warning in ifelse(sum(x) < 3, warning("Not OK", immediate. = T), "OK") :
  Not OK
  county response.out response.warning
1      A            3               OK
2      B            2           Not OK
3      C            4               OK


errors <- df |> filter(sum(response == 1) < 3, .by = county) |> select(county) |> unique()

gives:
> errors
  county
1      B

we are filtering if, per county (.by = county), the number of responses = 1 (sum(response == 1)) is fewer than three, selecting just the county name and giving you a column of unique counties matching that criterion.

I don't know if this is precisely what you are asking for, but you can do something like this:
checkCounties <- function(data){
    grouped_df <- data %>% 
        group_by(county) %>% 
        summarise(ResponseCount = sum(response))
    
    insufficient_responses <- grouped_df %>% filter(ResponseCount < 3)
    
    if (nrow(insufficient_responses) > 0) {
        counties_list <- paste(insufficient_responses$county, collapse = ", ")
        stop("Error: The following counties have a response count of less than 3: ", counties_list)
    } else {
        print("All counties have sufficient responses.")
    }
}

checkCounties(df)

Output:
> checkCounties(df)
Error in checkCounties(df) : 
  Error: The following counties have a response count of less than 3: B

If you don't want an error message to appear, you can swap out the stop() for print():
print(paste("Error: The following counties have a response count of less than 3: ", counties_list))


Sounds like you need to sum response by county group and then filter to keep counties that have n < 3.
library(dplyr)
df |> summarize(n = sum(response), .by = county) |>
  filter(n < 3)

Putting that in a function that can do a warning:
check_response_threshold <- function(df){
  too_low = df |> 
    summarize(n = sum(response), .by = county) |>
    filter(n < 3)
  if(nrow(too_low) > 0) {
    warning(
      "These counties have less than 3 responses:\n",
      toString(too_low$county)
    )
  }
  invisible()
}

Running it on your sample data:
check_response_threshold(df)
# Warning message:
# In check_response_threshold(df) :
#   These counties have less than 3 responses:
# B



Maybe a similar solution using the dplyr package: count(df, "county", "response") (and then filter 'n stuff)

You could use warning() and set options(warn=), depending on whether you want a warning, an error or just the data. on.exit ensures that options are reset to original values after function exits. To gather the data we can use aggregate in list notation and subset.
> obs_warning <- \(x, ind='response', group='county', value=3, warn=1) {
+   oo <- options(warn=warn)
+   on.exit(options(oo))
+   a <- with(x, aggregate(list(sum=get(ind)), list(get(group)), sum))
+   res <- subset(a, sum < value)
+   names(res) <- c(group, paste(ind, names(res)[2], sep='_'))
+   if (nrow(res)) {
+     warning('Insufficient observations!', call.=FALSE)
+     res
+   }
+ }
> 
> obs_warning(df, warn=-1)
  county response_sum
2      B            2
> obs_warning(df, warn=1)  ## the default
Warning: Insufficient observations!
  county response_sum
2      B            2
> obs_warning(df, warn=2)
Error: (converted from warning) Insufficient observations!

If all is ok, the function just passes
> obs_warning(df, value=2)

Note, that the function also works for different datasets.
> obs_warning(mtcars, 'vs', 'gear')
Warning: Insufficient observations!
  gear vs_sum
3    5      1

NB: Sometimes a simple stopifnot will do.
> stopifnot(all(with(df, tapply(response, county, sum)) >= 3))
Error: all(with(df, tapply(response, county, sum)) >= 3) is not TRUE

